# How do I actually test a mint function using Truffle and the payable modifier in Solidity

Tags: truffle, erc-721, nft, openzeppelin, truffle-test

I'm creating a smart contract and trying to test it using Truffle. I'm a little stuck on how to call the mint function ( how to actually execute the transaction from the test function ). I know Im going about this all wrong in my test just not certain about the syntax when calling a payable function.

```
function myMint(uint256 numberOfTokens) external payable nonReentrant {
    require(saleActive,"Nope");
    require(numberOfTokens > 0, "You cannot mint 0.");
    require(SafeMath.add(_numMinted.current(), numberOfTokens) <= MAX_PUBLIC_MINT, "Exceeds maximum supply.");
    require(numberOfTokens <= MAX_PURCHASE, "Exceeds maximum number");
    require(getNFTPrice(numberOfTokens) <= msg.value, "The Amount of Ether sent is not correct.");

    for(uint i = 0; i < numberOfTokens; i++){
        uint256 tokenIndex = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _numMinted.increment();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenIndex);   
    }
}
```

and in my test function

```
  describe('minting', async () => {

    it('creates a new token', async () => {
      const open = await contract.startSale();
      const result = await debug(contract.myMint(1));
    })
  })
```

Comment: What's the `debug` thing that wraps the call?

Comment: @Ismael if you are using Truffle to test ( mocha ) than you can wrap calls in debug (), if you run "truffle test debug" in the command line it lets you inspect the objects

Answer (score 2):

It is failing because you aren't sending any ether and the function requires some amount

```
require(getNFTPrice(numberOfTokens) <= msg.value, "The Amount of Ether sent is not correct.");
```

To send amount use the value paremeter `contract.myMint(1, { value: web3.utils.toWei("0.01", "ether") })`. For example

```
describe('minting', async () => {

    it('creates a new token', async () => {
        const open = await contract.startSale();
        const result = await debug(contract.myMint(1, {
            from: "0x12341234..",
            value: web3.utils.toWei("0.01", "ether"),
        }));
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use web3, you need to add `.call()` after the methods calls, like that : `contract.myMint(1).call()`.
If you use ethersjs, your call is good.

In all cases, method calls are async operations, you need to await for the result : `const result = await debug(await contract.myMint(1));`

Comment: Right, but my method myMint is payable ( so I think you need to use send() instead of call() ) but the syntax is still throwing an error, I'm trying to do this from within my Truffle test.js file, from what I understand and instance of web3 is available as well, this seams like a common use case, call a payable function with one parameter while sending payment, but I can't seem to find a working example